# How to increase the responsiveness of 'ManagementEventWatcher' logic?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi, responsiveness

I'm suscribed to `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` class events to notify when a process is ran on the PC:

```
Me.processStartWatcher = 
    New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"))
```

However, this seems not efficient because it takes 1 or 2 seconds to fire the event after I ran an executable file:

```
Private Sub ProcessStartWatcher_EventArrived(sender As Object, e As EventArrivedEventArgs) _
Handles processStartWatcher.EventArrived

    If (Me.ProcessStartedEvent IsNot Nothing) Then
        RaiseEvent ProcessStarted(Me, e)
    End If

End Sub
```

This means that if a process is ran and has exited quickly then I will not be notified.

Is there something I could do to increase responsiveness on a `ManagementEventWatcher` object?.

I tried to set the `Timeout` property but as the description of the member says, it seems does have nothing to do with this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [`WITHIN` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your WMI query to specify the polling interval.  The article gives plenty of warning that using small intervals is not recommended.  But forge ahead and try it anyway:

```
Me.processStartWatcher = 
    New ManagementEventWatcher(
       New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WITHIN 0.1"))
```

And you'll find out that it simply doesn't make any difference, the default is already as fast as it can be.  This is architectural in Windows, the kernel has no 'hook' to generate a notification when a process is created.  Important as it might be to, say, a virus scanner.  They are forced to patch the OS to be able to jump in.  The WMI provider that implements this query (C:\Windows\System32\wbem\KrnlProv.dll) does not do this.

Another way to see this is to just implement it yourself with the Process class.  For example:

```
Public Class ProcessMonitor
    Public Event Started As Action(Of Integer)
    Public Event Stopped As Action(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(interval As Integer)
        Me.interval = interval
        running = Scan()
        timer = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf callback, Nothing, interval, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub callback(state As Object)
        Dim active As HashSet(Of Integer) = Scan()
        Dim started As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = active.Except(running)
        Dim stopped As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = running.Except(active)
        running = active
        For Each pid As Integer In started
            RaiseEvent started(pid)
        Next
        For Each pid As Integer In stopped
            RaiseEvent stopped(pid)
        Next
        timer.Change(interval, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Function Scan() As HashSet(Of Integer)
        Dim ret As New HashSet(Of Integer)
        For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            ret.Add(proc.Id)
        Next
        Return ret
    End Function

    Private running As HashSet(Of Integer)
    Private timer As System.Threading.Timer
    Private interval As Integer
End Class
```

With a sample program that uses it:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim monitor As New ProcessMonitor(100)
        AddHandler monitor.Started, AddressOf Started
        AddHandler monitor.Stopped, AddressOf Stopped
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Sub Started(pid As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}", Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName)
    End Sub
    Sub Stopped(pid As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped: {0}", pid)
    End Sub
End Module
```

No difference.

Comment: Thankyou for answer, I noted a big good responsiveness difference using a threading.timer, however, I have a little doubt about the code you've provided, the unused **state** object in the Callback signature is necessary or can be removed?. I read in MSDN that object is used to turn off the timer, then?. Also, Idid an extended adaption of your code, I will publish it a different answer here to help other people who maybe has the same issue, with your permissions, can I?